# how to get the game object's same type as the rightHorizontalBound? so i could compare their values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have `gameobject charTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Character");`

And I am getting world borders with code 
`rightHorizontalBound = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (1,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;`

Question: how to get the game object's same type as the `rightHorizontalBound`?
so i could compare their values?

All bad happens in `if(charTransform1.position.x >= rightHorizontalBound)`, because of `charTransform1.position.x` is not a WorldPoint as a `rightHorizontalBound`.

The function where i compere is need so Character cannot go through the right border, here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gameplay : MonoBehaviour 
{

 float leftHorizontalBound;
 float rightHorizontalBound;

 public Transform charTransform1;

 void Start () 
 {
  charTransform1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Character").transform;
  leftHorizontalBound = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;
  rightHorizontalBound = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (1,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;
  //
 }


 void Update ()
 {
  MovementRight ();
  MovementLeft ();


  if (charTransform1.position.x <= leftHorizontalBound) {
     charTransform1.position = new Vector3 (leftHorizontalBound + 1f, charTransform1.position.y, charTransform1.position.z);
     return;
  } 

  if(charTransform1.position.x >= rightHorizontalBound)
  {
   charTransform1.position = new Vector3(rightHorizontalBound - 1f,charTransform1.position.y,charTransform1.position.z);
   return;
  }

 }

 void MovementRight()
 {
  charTransform1.transform.Translate (Vector2.right  300f  Time.deltaTime);
 }
 void MovementLeft()
 {
  charTransform1.transform.Translate (Vector3.left  00f  Time.deltaTime);
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed camera?

Comment: It's in 2D but I'm sure you could adapt it to your needs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mq4BlZLReKk